# spark 2.2 cache() cause the driver OutOfMemoryerror

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running Spark 2.2 with Scala on AWS EMR (Zeppling / spark-shell).

I'm trying to calculate very simple calculation: Loading, filtering, caching and counting on a large data set. My data contain 4,500 GB (4.8 TB) ORC format with 51,317,951,565 (51 billion) rows.

first I tried the process it with the following cluster:

> 1 master node - m4.xlarge - 4 cpu, 16 gb Mem
>
> 150 core nodes - r3.xlarge - 4 cpu, 29 gb Mem
>
> 150 tasks nodes - r3.xlarge - 4 cpu, 29 gb Mem

but it failed with `OutOfMemoryError`.

When I looked at Spark UI and Ganglia I saw that after the application load more than 80% of the data, the driver node getting too busy while the executors stop working (CPU usage is very low) until it crashed.

[Ganglia CPU usage for master and worker nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW1oy.png)

then I tried to execute the same process just with increasing the driver node to:

> 1 master node - m4.2xlarge - 8 cpu, 31 gb Mem

and it succeeds.

I don't understand why the Driver node Memory usage is being fulfilled until it crashes. AFAIK only the executors are loading and processing the tasks and the data should not pass to the master. what could be the reason for it?

1) [Ganglia Master Node usage for the second scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjN4j.png)

2) [Spark UI stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihwL4.png)

3) [Spark UI DAG visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grT4r.png)

Below you can find the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SaveMode, SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat_ws, expr, lit, udf}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

val df = spark.sql("select * from default.level_1 where date_  >= ('2017-11-08') and date_  <= ('2017-11-27')")
.drop("carrier", "city", "connection_type", "geo_country", "geo_country","geo_lat","geo_lon","geo_lon","geo_type", "ip","keywords","language","lat","lon","store_category","GEO3","GEO4")
.where("GEO4 is not null")
.withColumn("is_away", lit(0))


df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
df.count()
```

Below you can find the error message -

```
{"Event":"SparkListenerLogStart","Spark Version":"2.2.0"}
{"Event":"SparkListenerBlockManagerAdded","Block Manager ID":{"Executor ID":"driver","Host":"10.44.6.179","Port":44257},"Maximum Memory":6819151872,"Timestamp":1512024674827,"Maximum Onheap Memory":6819151872,"Maximum Offheap Memory":0}
{"Event":"SparkListenerEnvironmentUpdate","JVM Information":{"Java Home":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-1.b16.32.amzn1.x86_64/jre","Java Version":"1.8.0_141 (Oracle Corporation)","Scala Version":"version 2.11.8"},"Spark Properties":{"spark.sql.warehouse.dir":"hdfs:///user/spark/warehouse","spark.yarn.dist.files":"file:/etc/spark/conf/hive-site.xml","spark.executor.extraJavaOptions":"-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'","spark.driver.host":"10.44.6.179","spark.history.fs.logDirectory":"hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps","spark.eventLog.enabled":"true","spark.driver.port":"33707","spark.shuffle.service.enabled":"true","spark.driver.extraLibraryPath":"/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native","spark.repl.class.uri":"spark://10.44.6.179:33707/classes","spark.jars":"","spark.yarn.historyServer.address":"ip-10-44-6-179.ec2.internal:18080","spark.stage.attempt.ignoreOnDecommissionFetchFailure":"true","spark.repl.class.outputDir":"/mnt/tmp/spark-52cac1b4-614f-43a5-ab9b-5c60c6c1c5a5/repl-9389c888-603e-4988-9593-86e298d2514a","spark.app.name":"Spark shell","spark.scheduler.mode":"FIFO","spark.driver.memory":"11171M","spark.executor.instances":"200","spark.default.parallelism":"3200","spark.resourceManager.cleanupExpiredHost":"true","spark.executor.id":"driver","spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS":"$(hostname -f)","spark.driver.extraJavaOptions":"-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'","spark.submit.deployMode":"client","spark.master":"yarn","spark.ui.filters":"org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter","spark.blacklist.decommissioning.timeout":"1h","spark.executor.extraLibraryPath":"/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native","spark.sql.hive.metastore.sharedPrefixes":"com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2","spark.executor.memory":"20480M","spark.driver.extraClassPath":"/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar","spark.home":"/usr/lib/spark","spark.eventLog.dir":"hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps","spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled":"true","spark.executor.extraClassPath":"/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar","spark.sql.catalogImplementation":"hive","spark.executor.cores":"8","spark.history.ui.port":"18080","spark.driver.appUIAddress":"http://ip-10-44-6-179.ec2.internal:4040","spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_HOSTS":"ip-10-44-6-
```

Notes -

1) I tried to change the StorageLevel to `cache()` and `DISK_ONLY` and it didn't affect the result.

2) I checked the volume of the "scratch space" and I saw that more than 90% of it still not in use.

Thanks!!

Comment: You have not posted an error message, only info events.

Comment: Perhaps you are persisting the dataframe as you re-use it later? As there is no reason to persist if the code you have posted is your entire program, as the df is only used once.

Answer (score 0):

I have some assumption that this may be caused by the mechanism inside spark SQL.

In short the spark SQL will collect all the broadcast dataset at driver side so that when you have a big query, the driver must have enough memory to hold the broadcasted data.

Related [link to the issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12837)

Comment: I'm not sure, my query above is not including any join or broadcast, just simple filtration and count().